# OpenTSDB default metrics

Tags: metrics, opentsdb

I try to use OpenTSDB and does it has default metrics, for example cpu or smth else? I can create custom metric and put data, but does OpenTSDB provide some metrics under the hood? If this one provide this possibility, how can i turn on this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TCollector](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector). It has a number of built-in metrics.